# Why does Scala match fail for tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

I am exploring match feature with tuple and I can't seem to understand why this would throw error:

```
val t = (2,3)
val params = t match {
  case t._1 == 2 => println("first element is 2")
  case t._2 == 3 => println("second element is 3")
  case _ => println("no matches")
}
```

It throws following error for match statements 1 and 2

```
not found: value ==
```

Would appreciate if someone can explain why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the `match` a simple condition, but a `match` expression requires a pattern that is matched against the value and an optional condition preceded by `if`.

So in your case it would look like this:

```
val t = (2,3)
val params = t match {
  case (a, _) if a == 2 => println("first element is 2")
  case (_, b) if b == 3 => println("second element is 3")
  case _ => println("no matches")
}
```

> Edited to fix error pointed out in the comments

Comment: that did work which makes me think it failed in my case since I was doing `t match ...` and in my cases, I wasn't comparing it with tuples, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: the second case should probably check the second value of the tuple: case (_, a)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You have to `match` a *thing* with a different *thing* (or the description of a *thing*). You can't `match` a *thing* with a condition.

---

```
t match {
  case a => // a and t are the same
}
```

That will always match because the value of `t` can be placed in the new variable `a`.

```
t match {
  case (a,b) => // a & b hold the values of the tuple elements
}
```

That will match only if `t` is a 2-tuple.

```
t match {
  case (a,b) if a < b => // a & b hold the values of the tuple elements only if a < b
}
```

That will match only if `t` is a 2-tuple AND the elements are comparable AND the 1st element is less than the 2nd.

Also note that `println()` returns `Unit` which means that your `params` variable will always have the same, empty value. Let's fix that along with the rest of you code.

```
val t = (2,3)
val status :String = t match {
  case (a,_) if a == 2 => "first element is 2"
  case (_,b) if b == 3 => "second element is 3"
  case _ => "no matches"
}
```

Notice that only one `case` can match. If the first one matches then none of the rest will be tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
val t = (2,3)
val params = t match {
  case (2, _) => println("first element is 2")
  case (_, 3) => println("second element is 3")
  case _ => println("no matches")
}
```